# Get an elements offset by using id stored in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to acquire the offset of an element by using its id, which I have stored inside an array. The code:

```
        var id_array = new Array;
        var offset_array = new Array;
        var i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < $(".page-grid-picture").length; i++)
        {                
            id_array.push($(".page-grid-picture")[i].getAttribute("id"));
            offset_array.push(id_array[i].offset().top);
        }
```

I've used alert to see if the correct value is stored in the id_array, which it is. The problem is that I don't seem to able to use the value by calling it using its index when trying to get the offset value. If I use a unique id like this it works:

```
        offset_array.push($("#unique-id").offset().top);
```

But not when I try to use the id_array... I've also tried:

```
        offset_array.push(document.getElementById(id_array[i]).offset().top);
```

That didn't work either...

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There should be an error in the console (_... is not a function_) -> http://api.jquery.com/get/; Your loop queries the DOM at least `n + 1` times (or in the worst case `2*n`) for elements with the class `.page-grid-picture` where `n` is the number of elements with that class.

Comment: The elements in the id_array are not jQuery objects.  `offset()` is a jQuery method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `offset()` on a jQuery object.  It is not a method on a String or raw DOM Element.

```js
var id_array = [];
var offset_array = [];
var $pageGridPictures = $(".page-grid-picture");

$pageGridPictures.each(function(index, element){
  var $this = $(element);
  
  id_array.push(element.id);
  offset_array.push($this.offset().top);
});
```

Originally you were doing the following:

```
id_array.push($(".page-grid-picture")[i].getAttribute("id"));
```

What that does is finds all the page grid picture elements as a jQuery object.  It then gets the `[i]` element, which breaks a single DOM Element out of the jQuery object, and then gets the id attribute off of it.  So the value pushed to the id_array in that case is a string, not a jQuery object.  So if you were going to do it this way, you'd have to later grab the id, look the element up again, and then do offset() off of it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm :)